# Got a problem with list creation function in generic linked list library

Tags: c

I found a generic linked list library which I thought would be useful. But the llist_create(void *new_data) function is confusing me. The pointer new_list is allocated two times. What I can see is that the address returned by first malloc will be overwritten by second malloc. So why use the first malloc? (Code works perfectly)

Since I got curious I tried to run by commenting the first malloc. Then gcc gave a warning "initialization from incompatible pointer type". Running the code gives segmentation fault.

```
struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node * llist;   


llist *llist_create(void *new_data)
{
    struct node *new_node;

    //First alloc
    llist *new_list = (llist *)malloc(sizeof (llist));
    //Second alloc
    *new_list = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));

    new_node = *new_list;
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_list;
}

 //Code which creates linked list in driver program
 llist *my_list = llist_create(NULL);
```

Comment: `llist_create` returns `struct node **` (no idea why not just `struct node *`). The first `malloc` allocates space for `struct node *` (i.e. for `*new_list`), the second one - for `struct node`, which `*new_list` points to.

Comment: first malloc for pointer to pointer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not familiar with [typedef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) in c.

> typedef is a reserved keyword in the C and C++ programming languages. It is used to create an alias name for another data type.1 As such, it is often used to simplify the syntax of declaring complex data structures consisting of struct and union types, but is just as common in providing specific descriptive type names for integer data types of varying lengths.

Now look at this statement:

```
typedef struct node * llist;
```

This means, `llist` is an alias name for `struct node *` type.

In this statement

```
llist *new_list = (llist *)malloc(sizeof (llist));
```

the type of `new_list` is `llist *` which is nothing but `struct node **`.

So, the first memory allocation to `new_list` is for pointer to pointer to `struct node` and the second allocation is for pointer to `struct node`.

---

IMO, the code posted by OP is confusing because of two reasons:
- typedef a pointer to structure
- The two operations creation of list and adding node in that list is combined in one function.

A more readable code would be something like this:

```
struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

struct llist {
    NODE *head;
};

typedef struct llist LLIST;

LLIST *create_list() {
    LLIST *llist = malloc(sizeof(LLIST));
    if (llist == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    llist->head = NULL;
    return llist;
}

NODE *create_ll_node(void *data) {
    NODE *node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (node == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

// The add function for inserting node at the start of list
// Parameter: pointer to LLIST
//            data to be insert in node
void add_list_head(LLIST *llist, void *data) {
    NODE *node = create_ll_node(data);
    if (llist->head != NULL) {
        node->next = llist->head;
    }
    llist->head = node;
}

//driver function
int main() {
    LLIST *llist = create_list();
    .....
    .....

    add_list_head(llist, <data>);
    add_list_head(llist, <data>);
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
llist *llist_create(void *new_data)
```

Is performing 2 operations, it is creating a new list head, and creating a node, with a data reference for the head.

```
llist *new_list = (llist *)malloc(sizeof (llist));
```

Firstly creates a list head by declaring a new variable of type llist *, and using malloc to create the memory for this pointer.

```
//Second alloc
*new_list = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
```

Creates a new `node` to hold the provided data.
Confusingly in `C` syntax both `*new_list` mean different things.

```
llist *new_list; /* create a variable of pointer to llist */
```

and

```
*new_list = val; /* write into what new_list is pointing at val */
```

The remainder of the function fills out the `node` with the `new_data`